# Oddity in definition(s) of quasi compact operator

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, probability-theory, ergodic-theory

I was wondering about the general definition of a quasicompact operator. There seem to be two main ones floating around in the literature, and I am not sure they are equivalent. The first, and seemingly most prevalent one is that an operator $T:B \to B$ is quasi-compact, if there exists a natural number $n$, and a compact operator $K$, so that
$$
\|T^n-K\|<1
$$
The second definition says that $T$ is quasi-compact, if there exists two closed, invariant subspaces $F, H$, so that
$$
B=F\oplus H
$$
with $dim(F) <\infty$, so that the spectral radius of $T$ restricted to $H$ is strictly less than the spectral radius of $T$, $r(T)$, and any eigenvalue of $T$ restricted to $F$ has magnitude $r(T)$.

My main query is that, whilst these definitions seem to be equivalent in the special case when $r(T) = 1$, the second definition seems to imply that the class of quasi-compact operators is stable under scalar multiplication, whilst the first does not. I believe I came up with an example which I will put at the end of the question. A seemingly simple fix would be to require that $\|T^n-K\| < r(T)^n$, but I haven't seen it used anywhere.
I guess since these operators mainly show up in ergodic theory, having unit norm is very natural, and so perhaps this is how the convention was born. Nevertheless, having read quite a few papers now which use definition 1 in the form I stated, I was still wondering if perhaps I had perhaps missed something.

$\textbf{Example:}$

Let $B$ be a Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $e_i$. Define now an operator $T:B \to B$ by $Te_i=e_i$ for $i >1$, and $Te_1=2e_1$. This operator is quasi-compact in the sense of definition 2 (take $F=span\{e_1\}$, $H=\overline{span\{e_i:i\geq 2\}}$), but not the sense of definition 1. However, $\frac{T}{\|T\|}$ is again quasi-compact in the sense of definition 1. To see $T$ is not quasicompact in the sense of definition 1,  note that $T^n$ still agrees with $T$ on any $e_i$ with $i \geq 2$. Thus, if $K$ is compact and $\|T^n-K\|<1$, there must exists a constant $a>0$ so that for all $i \geq 2$, it holds
$$
|1-\langle e_i,Ke_i\rangle|\leq \|T^ne_i-Ke_i\|\leq 1-a
$$
so that $a \leq |\langle e_i,Ke_i\rangle|$. By the compactness assumption, since the sequence $\{e_i\}$ converges weakly to zero, $Ke_i$ must converge to zero in norm. But then $\|Ke_i\|\geq a$ for any $i \geq 2$, so this cannot be.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this topic, but definition 2 looks really weird to me. You have that $I+2P$, with $P$ rank-one, is quasicompact. But $I+\frac12\,P$, which is again a compact perturbation of the identity by a rank-one operator, is not quasidiagonal? What kind of definition is this, that does not survive perturbations by compact operators?

Comment: *(continued)* There are also compact operators which are not quasicompact according to definition 2: any compact operator with spectrum $\{0\}$, like the Volterra operator, cannot be quasicompact because $H$ cannot exist.

Comment: I am just learning about this topic, so take my following comments with a grain of salt. Definition 2 is from [here](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/b87874).  The way I have understood the definition of quasi-compactness, is as a sort of generalisation of the notion of a spectral gap. Since these are not stable under arbitrary compact pertubations, it would make sense that neither is quasicompactness. (e.g. if $T=T_1+T_2$, is the usual splitting according to eigenprojections, where $T_2$ is rank one and $T_1$ has spectral radius less than $1$, then $T-T_2$ has no spectral gap).

Comment: I guess in this way, the name quasi-compactness is perhaps a bit of a misnomer. The issue of quasinilpotent compact operators can probably be resolved by tweaking the definition slightly to exclude such possibilities.

Comment: Then again, the more I look at this, the more it seems to me like the two definitions describe fundamentally different objects, which just so happen to coincide when $r(T)=1$. (In case anyone is interested, the equivalence when $r(T)=1$ follows essentially from Lemma VIII.8.2 from "Linear operators, Part 1 : general theory" by Dunford and Schwartz. Since any eigenvalue $\lambda$ with $|\lambda|^n >\|T^n-K\|$ is isolated, there can be at most finitely many larger than any given magnitude. (otherwise there is an accumulation point), so just take the projection onto the largest ones).